# Como preencher múltiplas tags em um if/else utilizando XQuery?

Tags: if

Eu quero fazer algo como:

```
for $var in $myValueOfVar
    return
        if ($var= "X") then
            <tagA>A</tagA>
            <tagB>B</tagB>
            <tagC>C</tagC>
        else
            <tagD>D</tagD>
}
```

Mas recebo o seguinte erro:

> Invalid expression, expecting ELSE, found '>'

Então eu tentei utilizar 4 `if`'s, um para cada tag, como abaixo:

```
for $var in $myValueOfVar
    return
        if ($var= "X") then
            <tagA>A</tagA>
        else
            ()
        if ($var= "X") then
            <tagB>B</tagB>
        else
            ()
        if ($var= "X") then
            <tagC>C</tagC>
        else
            ()
        if ($var != "X") then
            <tagD>D</tagD>
        else
            ()
}
```

Porém recebo o seguinte erro:

> Invalid expression: unexpected token: if

Qual é a forma correta para fazer isto? Não achei nenhum exemplo seguindo esta linha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de algum tempo pesquisando, tive resposta na própria comunidade do StackOverflow (porém na  gringa), a solução segue abaixo, caso alguém se depare com o mesmo cenário:

```
for $var in $myValueOfVar
    return
        if ($var= "X") then (
            <tagA>A</tagA>,
            <tagB>B</tagB>,
            <tagC>C</tagC>,
        )
        else
            <tagD>D</tagD>
}
```